# can't get an android emulator to work in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have tried various configurations, but I can't get an AVD to work in Eclipse. The emulator opens to the initial "android" screen, but it just sits there. I have looked at the logcat file while it is trying to load, and the logcat file is constantly getting entries - most of them errors.

This is the current AVD I've created and tried to run:

```
Device: Nexus One  
Target: Android 4.0 - API Level 14  
CPU/ABI: ARM (armeabe-v7a)  
Keyboard: x Hardware keyboard present  
Skin: Skin with dynamic hardware controls  
Front Camera: None  
Back Camera: None  
RAM: 512    VM Heap: 12  
Internal Storage: 200
```

Here is the last part of my latest logcat file, if anyone wants to sift through it to see if they can find what the problem is (very sorry it is so long, but the viewer is set on verbose):

```
09-12 15:19:27.891: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:27.891: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:27.891: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:27.901: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/SoundRecorder.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:27.991: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:27.991: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:27.991: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:28.111: E/installd(1247): Could not create directories; exiting.
09-12 15:19:28.121: E/keystore(1248): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
09-12 15:19:28.181: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/Email.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:28.321: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 49% free 10813K/20935K, paused 8ms+31ms
09-12 15:19:28.641: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 883K, 51% free 10429K/20935K, paused 5ms+6ms
09-12 15:19:29.161: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 177K, 49% free 10724K/20935K, paused 5ms+7ms
09-12 15:19:29.631: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:29.631: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:29.631: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:29.661: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/PackageInstaller.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:29.761: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 48% free 10966K/20935K, paused 5ms+7ms
09-12 15:19:29.971: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:29.981: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:29.981: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:30.011: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/Gallery.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:30.361: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 47% free 11101K/20935K, paused 5ms+16ms
09-12 15:19:30.571: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:30.571: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:30.571: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:30.581: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/Protips.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:30.681: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:30.681: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:30.681: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:31.001: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/Settings.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:31.181: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1001K, 50% free 10612K/20935K, paused 6ms+29ms
09-12 15:19:31.531: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K, 50% free 10614K/20935K, paused 6ms+5ms
09-12 15:19:31.671: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 49% free 10754K/20935K, paused 9ms+5ms
09-12 15:19:32.161: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 49% free 10865K/20935K, paused 6ms+8ms
09-12 15:19:32.721: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 185K, 47% free 11191K/20935K, paused 7ms+6ms
09-12 15:19:33.151: E/installd(1249): Could not create directories; exiting.
09-12 15:19:33.201: E/keystore(1250): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
09-12 15:19:33.381: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:33.401: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:33.401: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:33.411: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/SpeechRecorder.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:33.471: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 46% free 11514K/20935K, paused 5ms+10ms
09-12 15:19:33.661: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:33.661: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:33.691: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:33.711: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/PicoTts.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:33.791: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:33.791: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:33.801: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:33.811: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/SettingsProvider.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:33.901: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:33.901: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:33.901: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:33.922: I/PackageManager(1219): /system/app/DefaultContainerService.apk changed; collecting certs
09-12 15:19:34.071: I/Installer(1219): connecting...
09-12 15:19:34.071: I/Installer(1219): disconnecting...
09-12 15:19:34.081: E/Installer(1219): connection failed
09-12 15:19:34.161: D/dalvikvm(1219): GC_CONCURRENT freed 646K, 46% free 11346K/20935K, paused 6ms+21ms
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Intel processor, you could try downloading HAXM from the Android SDK Manager to speed up the emulator.  If that doesn't work you could try using an different emulator such as [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) which runs in VirtualBox.